# Will Firefox start my SDK extension automatically after the browser starts - loading screen

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am new on add-on development using the SDK.

1. I want to ask you guys if it is possible to start my extension automatically after I open my browser? At the moment I starts after I press my widget icon in the toolbar (the panel shows a table with some data I get from the DOM).
2. Another thing I want to ask you: is it possible to show a loading screen (like a ajax gif) inside my panel (my extension needs a few seconds after switching a tab, to get the DOM data) every time I press the toolbar button.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: One question per post, please.

1. Extensions are always started with the browser. When it comes to SDK add-ons, your `main.js` will be called. It's your job to perform any additional initialization form there.
2. Panels contain regular HTML pages and therefore can use images.

It's impossible to tell you more, without you providing more details and the code you got so far!

Comment: Hey, 

thanks for your fast answer.
Sorry that i asked two questions at once!

 1. Okey, after i changed a few things in my main class it works the way i want it to!
 2. Thanks, i will try it this way.